# Writing Excel formula to check all rows if they have same IDs but different file names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a long list of data within an excel sheet, I am going to be changing the file IDs to names instead. The problem is I need to first check whether there are different IDs for the same file name, as this would create a problem.

So for the columns file_id and the column File_name I need help writing a formula that would compare wherther there are two or more IDs for the same file name.

Is this possible?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Infront of a column (File_name), there can be multiple columns which correspond to different file IDs right?

Comment: Is file_id numeric or alphanumeric ? There is dirty trick that can be used if its only numeric.

Comment: @KartikAnand I want to check if there are different File_Ids to the File_Names. There can be many File_Names they all must have the same File_ID for the name. I just want to check if there is a different file_id for the same file_name.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur the file_id is numeric thanks

Comment: @Ricky If possible can you please put up an example data set (a picture or something) showing your sheet

Comment: @KartikAnand I have added a picture showing an example. I need the check to point out for example id no.5 which shows a different file_id for the same file_name. Thanks

Comment: @Ricky Will the filenames occur like this only, or can they occur again after sometime, For eg. can "Stack" occur after "Flow" ?

Comment: @KartikAnand no they will only occur as they are shown there are other names but they are grouped together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's is my attempt. What this code would do is mark those file name whose id doesn't match with the previous IDs. Look at the picture below :

[image: Snapshot]

I've attempted it using VBA

Press ALT + F11 to enter VBA, on the left hand column you'll see "Project -VBA Project", under this double click on Sheet1, or whatever is the name of your sheet on which you're working.

[image: VBA mode]

[image: Pasted code]

Paste the following code there:

```
Sub mark()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim name As String

    Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$2")
    row = 0

    Do Until rng.Offset(row, 0) = ""

        id = rng.Offset(row, 0)
        name = rng.Offset(row, 1)

        Do While rng.Offset(row, 1) = name
            If rng.Offset(row, 0) <> id Then
                rng.Offset(row, 0).Interior.Color = 255
                rng.Offset(row, 1).Interior.Color = 255
            End If
            row = row + 1
        Loop

    Loop

End Sub
```

## Keep the following in mind

1. In my code the name of the sheet is "**Sheet1**", if the name of your sheet is something else then edit the below line in the code as follows

   ```
   Set rng = Sheets("Your sheet name").Range("$A$2")
   ```
2. In my code, the starting Range(Cell) has been specified as **A2**, if the starting cell is something else for example **D2**, then edit the line in the code as follows

   ```
   Set rng = Sheets("Your sheet name").Range("$D$2")
   ```

If you want to do some thing else with these cells instead of marking them, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Column A is ID and Column B is Name
The following will check if there is more than one ID for each name.
Paste in Cell C1 and drag down.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,"<>"&B1,A:A,A1)>0,"MORE THAN ONE ID FOR THIS NAME","OK")
```

Note that the 'COUNTIFS()' Function is only for excel 2007, 2010.

If you have an older version of Excel you need to use an array formula which will look like this:

```
=IF(SUM(IF(A:A=A1,IF(B:B<>B1,1,0),0))>0,"MORE THAN ONE ID FOR THIS NAME","OK")
```

To make it work You'll have to push Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering the formula.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I mean for example there are two file names in B2 called STACK for this file name I need to know whether there is a different file_id for the name stack. There are many file names thanks

Comment: AH i thought you wanted to know if there were multiple file_id's for the same file name. Just reverse the A and B's in either of the above formulas to do it the other way around

Comment: Sorry there can be many file_ids but they must remain the same for the file_name, the check is only to see if the filenames is used in different Ids which it shouldnt be. If the name is stack all file ids should be 1, if it is over all will be 2, but if there was one that had over and 3 I would want the check to point this out. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple columns for file_id and only one column for File_name and the entries in the File_name column are unique, then it is pretty straightforward:
Say columns A, B, and C contain the file_id information and column D contains the File_name.  In column E, you would put this formula:  `=COUNTA(A2:C2)`

This will count the number of file_id entries in the columns to the left of your File_name column.  If the result is more than 1, you know there are multiple file_ids present.

Comment: I think he means that there is only one ID column, and is afraid that the same ID number is being used for multiple textnames.